# Raspberry Pi 3 B+ doesn't boot up. Only PWR LED is on

Tags: boot-issues, pi-3b+

Just got new Pi3 B+ today from reseller.
I went ahead and test it out and it doesn't work. Only PWR LED was lit.
I tried another SD card and still doesn't work.
I also tried reflashing Raspbian instead of NOOBS and still doesn't work.
I supposed it's the Polyfuse that blew up.

EDIT : Forgot to provide that I use Official Raspberry Pi adapter. I even tested it with my Pi3B and all my 3 PiZeroes

EDIT #2 : And again, I forgot to provide that there's no video output. But when I first got it the Pi actually had video output and green LED blinked few times (I didn't count them)

Comment: It is not the polyfuse, the red PWR led would be out.  The SD card is not formatted properly.  How did you "reflash" it?

Comment: I reflashed using "etcher.io" with Rasbian 9 image

Answer (score 1):

> I reflashed using "etcher.io" with Rasbian 9 image

It is almost certainly that it is rejected the SD card -- it will behave the same way with no card in (just the red PWR led comes on, check this to make sure). This probably means the [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MBR) or first partition are invalid. If it can read anything in the first partition, even if none of the right files are present, the green ACT led will flash in a repeated sequence until you pull the plug (this is different from the irregular flashing that accompanies a normal boot).  It can also happen if the SD card reader is broken.

I would try double checking the card is inserted correctly.  You can also check the card itself in a normal computer.  While you won't be able to see the second partition containing the root filesystem (unless you are using linux or something else that can read ext4fs), you should be able to see the small first partition, ~50 MB, VFAT formatted, with files like `kernel.img`, `bootcode.bin`, and various `fixup...` files.  If you cannot read this first partition at all, then the card has not been formatted correctly or has become corrupted.

Comment: It does have those files you referred to. And I can use SD card to boot on my other Pi

Answer (score 1):

Considering the SD card works in other pi's, and the power supply works in other pi's consider the following:

1. create an image on a USB thumb drive - just as you would an sd card - and try to boot from that. It is my understanding (I could be wrong) that the Pi 3B+ can boot from USB out of the box
2. it may be just dirty contacts in the SD slot - not sure how to check and/or clean them
3. it could be faulty - it happens